# Inserir, somar e exibir valor (em reais) usando PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, formulário, decimal

Olá, sou iniciante em PHP e MySQL. Gostaria de ter um formulário onde eu insira um valor (em reais, no caso), some com o que já tenha salvo no banco de dados, e por fim exiba para o usuário o resultado deste cálculo.

**É algo bem simples, apenas para estudo.**

Tenho um formulário e uma tabela no banco de dados com um campo do tipo DECIMAL. Já consigo salvar no banco de dados, porém se eu digito no input um valor do tipo "1.280,90", no meu banco de dados ele salva apenas como "1":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>jJulius</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $database = "jjulius";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {

        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

    }
    echo "Connected successfully";
    ?>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {
        $valor=$_POST['valor'];


        $sql = "INSERT INTO valor (valor) VALUES ";
        $sql .= "('$valor')"; 
        mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");
        mysqli_close($conn);

    }

    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="valor" />
        <button type="submit" name="save">Enviar</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar como salvar e exibir esses dados corretamente, por favor?

Desde já agradeço. :)

Comment: 1.280,90 não é um formato decimal para o banco de dados.

Comment: O formato correto para o valor 1.280,90, deveria ser 1280.90, formato padrão de números decimaisno MySql. você poderia fazer uma tratativa para conseguir este formato utilizando $valor = "1.280,90"; $valor = REPLACE( REPLACE( $valor, '.' ,'' ), ',', '.' ). e quando for exibir em tela fazer a tratativa para exibir novamente a estrutura novamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente, o campo `DECIMAL` do MySql exige precisão exata, por minha opção eu utilizo `FLOAT`.

Em seguida o valor que será salvo deve conter no máximo um `.` separando os decimais,  `1234.56` por exemplo, para isso precisa manter apenas os numeros e substituir a `,` por `.`.

A função [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php), aqui, mantém apenas os números e a vírgula:

```
$valor=preg_replace("/[^0-9,]+/i","",$_POST["valor"]);
```

A função [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php), aqui, substitui a vírgula pelo ponto final:

```
$valor=str_replace(",",".",$valor);
```

Executa o `INSERT`:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO valor (valor) VALUES ('$valor')"; 
mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");
```

Executa o `SELECT`, usando [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) para adicionar o `R$` ao resultado, e [COUNT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html) para somar os valores:

```
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT('R$ ', SUM(valor)) AS total FROM valor";

if($result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)):
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
        echo "Total: ".$row["total"];
    endwhile;
    mysqli_free_result($result);
endif;
```

Comment: Perfeito! Irei colocar uma máscara no formulário para que o número seja salvo da forma correta, muito obrigado!

Comment: Eu quem agradeço por ajudar, se puder marcar a resposta, agradecerei tbm.